# Screen scraping: how to get the image

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I'm working on a screen scraper to archive card data for a game I play.

Here's one of the pages: http://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=1,#hashid=1fc816f7545c2bd39f6cc7737803644c,#cardcount=2

This is my first screen scraper and it's been a lot easier than I initially expected, however I'm not quite sure how to go about getting the image file.  When I inspect the card picture, this is the html element that comes up:

```
<img width="428" height="600" src="showimage?prefix=printing&amp;cardid=1&amp;nestid=1&amp;class=details&amp;tagid=34&amp;hash=4c/a4,428,600,image/jpeg">
```

How would I go about getting the actual file?

In my code I am just using an HtmlDocument object to get at the HtmlElement's.

Comment: You need to browse to the url of the image using a `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` and then save the result from there. You already did something like that when you downloaded the html source.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Ok, but I'm still unclear on what the url would be... I tried just appending what was in the src attribute to the web address in a browser but got nothing.

Comment: Try using the Developer tool (F12) in browser and see images getting downloaded and look for your image. You'll get the actual source of image from there.

Comment: @vendettamit That's exactly what I did, and that's where I got the img element I posted in the question.  That's all I could find... did you try it and if so were you able to find an actual url to a flie?

Comment: The url from the sample you provided would be http://imperialassembly.com/oracle/showimage?prefix=printing&cardid=1&nestid=1&class=details&tagid=34&hash=4c/a4,428,600,image/jpeg

Comment: @vendettamit Nevermind, I was using IE and it wasn't clear to me what the web path should be before appending the src attribute but I just did it in Chrome and realized what I was doing wrong.  Thanks everybody!

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Sheesh, apparently the entire url is already in the src attribute but when inspecting it from IE I didn't realize it was shortening it.  Ah well, got it working now at least :)